# Server closes after loading homepage (locally)

Tags: node.js

I cant understand how and where to use response.end(). i get it working when loading only single response but when i try to load (say) two html files (index and form in my case) , the server does not load anything.
if i put res.end() after loading the index html it works but server closes.

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var url=require('url');
var path=require('path');
var fs=require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  filepath=path.join(__dirname,'index.html');
  fs.readFile(filepath,null,function(err,data){
    if(err){
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.write(err+" Error");
    }
    else{
      res.write(data);
    }
    res.end();
  });
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function () {
      res.write('File uploaded');
     res.end();
    });
  } else {
    var q=url.parse(req.url,true);
    var filename=path.join(__dirname,q.pathname);
    console.log(filename);
    fs.readFile(filename,function(err,data){
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.write(err+"404 Not Found");
      }
      else{
        res.write(data);
      }
      res.end();
    })
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Other tips on improving code is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

    if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function () {
            res.write('File uploaded');
            res.end();
        });
    } else if (req.url.length > 1) {
        var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
        var filename = path.join(__dirname, q.pathname);
        console.log(filename);
        fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(404);
                res.write(err + "404 Not Found");
            }
            else {
                res.write(data);
            }
            res.end();
        })
    } else {
        filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');
        fs.readFile(filepath, null, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(404);
                res.write(err + " Error");
            }
            else {
                res.write(data);
            }
            res.end();
        });
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: can you explain what happens when end() is used?

Comment: end() is used, we cannot use write() again.